# Custom thumnailers not working in trusty

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, dconf, thumbnails

For some reason, **dconf editor** is no longer able to customise thumnailers as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518889/how-to-disable-thumbnail-generation?answertab=active#tab-top).

I want to exclude pdfs and plain text thumbnails. I add `['application/pdf','text/plain']` to `org > gnome > desktop > thumbnailer > disable`, and (after deleting everything within ~/.thumbnails/ and rebooting) pdf and plain text thumbnails are still being displayed.

Any ideas as to what might be the problem?